# Cast record type to geometry type

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I cast type record /subquery/ to  geometry type? My example:

```
select  geom from  (select  (ST_Simplify..... ) as geom
```

and result is type record, but I need to convert to geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to cast, you just need to alias the output of the subquery appropriately.

```
SELECT geom 
FROM
  (SELECT ST_Simplify(geom) AS geom FROM mutable) AS subquery
WHERE thecolumn = 'the condition';
```